# Javascript Facebook API: Caching User Data

Tags: javascript, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a way I can cache user info on the clients system? For example, if I had a list of all of the users friends..via fql...is there a way to save that somewhere so that I don't have to request it on every use of the app?

I apologize if I've used incorrect terminology I'm an amateur programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can use one of the new HTML5 features

- http://ajaxian.com/archives/webkit-does-html5-client-side-database-storage
- http://html5demos.com/storage

You can also check to see if the broswer doesn't have that available, and use a server-side caching mechanism to your advantage such as memcached or application variables.

Answer (score 1):

Aside of HTML5 local storage (as suggested by [DCMS](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users/52087/dmcs) in other answer) there is also SQLite support in WebKit browsers and userData in older versions of Internet Explorer.

You can use something like [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) (it have support for jQuery, Prototye and MooTools) to support client-side storage in [most browsers](http://www.jstorage.info/#support).